# I have an "&" in one of my parameters passed while making an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an "&" in one of my parameters passed while making an ajax call. So on the Server-side code while receiving this parameter, only the part before the "&" is available. This Problem Does not occur for Parameters without a "&" substring in it

Tried to use `.toString()`

```
var url = '/Configuration/WorkCenters' + '?WorkCenterID=' + $('#WorkCenter_WorkCenterID').val() + '&WorkCenterName=' + $("#WorkCenter_WorkCenterName").val()
```

so if the Value of `$("#WorkCenter_WorkCenterName").val()` is "ABC & DEF" then at the server side i am only able to see "ABC"

Answer (score 2):

Use encodeURIComponent(name) to convert to a supported value and try it